# Parent/child relationship by ID within the same table

Tags: php, eloquent

I am trying to build a relationship for my model, Client. A Client can have a subclient (children) or it can be a child of another client (parent). Or, it can be by itself as just a client.

I have the Client model with columns id and name, and the ClientRelationship model with the columns client_id and parent_id.

ClientRelationship migration:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('client_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id');
$table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');
$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('clients');
```

And within the Client model:

```
public function parent()
{
return $this->hasOne(ClientRelationship::class);
}

public function children()
{
return $this->hasMany(ClientRelationship::class);
}
```

When I have this display on my blade template, parent is working and showing what it should be using:

```
@if ($client->parent)
   <li>{{ $client->parent->id }}</li>
@endif
```

However, children are not showing properly with:

```
@if ($client->children)
   @foreach ($client->children as $child)
      <li>{{ $child->id }}</li>
   @endforeach
@endif
```

Also, in a perfect would I'd have it displaying the client names, not IDs, but I wanted to first figure out why I can't get children to display properly.

Thanks for any advice, I feel like I must be missing something silly!

Answer (score 0):

Since a client may or may not have a parent, then `parent_id` should be nullable.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
```

Then to get children of a client, you are looking for all clients who have `parent_id` equals to its client id `id`.

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ClientRelationship::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

You don't need `client_id` field, `parent_id` field should suffice.